# usb drive not detected after formattinf on ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, usb-drive, disk, disk-utility, detect

The pen drive is visible on disk application. But it can't be formatted. It is not visible on gparted. I had formatted it. And this happened after it. It is not visible in files.

I tried it in my friend's pc which runs windows. Even though the pendrive didn't show up on the file explorer, a window appeared saying installing drivers. And when looked through the disk manager, I found out that the pendrive had been formatted to **'mbr'**.

[The image shows the disk application with the info about the pendrive.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrMDO.png)

Comment: If the flash drive says "No media" or is read only - it usually means that it is broken: https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only